# How can I adjust the size of a QDialog according to its title length?

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, resize

One of my dialog window's title is shortened (like "My Dialogt..."). If the dialog was slightly wider, the whole title would be completely displayed, which would look nicer.

It seems as if there is no setting in Qt to do that. I have found a hack for a `QMessageBox` here: [Can QMessageBox::about adjust size to title length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582896/can-qmessageboxabout-adjust-size-to-title-length), but it is not general. For example it would have to take also the sizes of the icons to the left and to the right of the window title into account to compute a really good minimal size where still the title is completely shown.

Is there a general way to accomplish that? Is there also a simple way to do that? Or is this overengineering?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582896/can-qmessageboxabout-adjust-size-to-title-length

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez Yes, this is the question that I have cited as being not general.

Comment: IMO, resizing a dialog based on the length of the title string is an example of bad GUI design, unless there is a specific reason for doing so.

Comment: @vahancho Why? (I do not want to say that you are wrong. I just would like to know your reasons.)

Comment: @BenjaminBihler, because I envision the following scenario: assume you have a window that shows on its title bar a full path of files you load. Now you open a file with a pretty long full path - your window spontaneously expands, probably up to off screen. Next time you open another file and your window shrinks and so on. How do you like it? I don't, because I want to control the window size myself. That's why Qt automatically cuts the title string without providing an API to expand the window.

Comment: @vahancho You are completely right. It definitely needs to be a feature that you can disable (or have to enable explicitely). The case here is that adding a few pixels to the dialog makes the whole title visible. And this is just nicer than a minimum size dialog with a partially visible title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only this goal is questionable (see [vahanco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2674506/vahancho) comment) but it is hard to achieve, because the **window title bar is not Qt territory at all**: apart from being able to set its text and manage to show or hide close/min/max button using window flags, there is little else in control, there.

By the way, a very raw way to set a dialog minimum width which could (*could*) make room to the whole text is the following:

```
const QString text = "Very very very very very very very very very very very very very long window title";
setWindowTitle(text);

QFontMetrics metrics(font(), this);
setMinimumWidth( metrics.horizontalAdvance(text));
```

This won't work out of the box, and it's very likely that the text stay cut, because the font used is **supposed** to be the same used in the title bar (which usually isn't) and we're not taking into account the frame width, the icon width, the title bar buttons width, and everything else which is owned by the window manager and is totally unknown to Qt.

So, you can **figure out** how much extra space is needed by all these stuff, and  adjust the width with a totally arbitrary extra padding like

```
setMinimumWidth( metrics.horizontalAdvance(text) + 256);
```

and maybe get what you wanted in the first place (if you still really want it).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

The below code works in QT 5.15. According to the documentation after you call setMinumumWidth() you must call updateGeometry() [update geometry docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#updateGeometry). Setting minimumWidth should update the sizeHint. That was not happening for me. Also QFontMetrics::horizontalAdvance was not returning the width of the text.  I had to use QFontMetrics::boundingRect({title_string}).width().
Calling resize on the dialog is what finally got it working for me. If the accepted answer doesn't work for you give this a try.

```
  QString message = "Message for the user";
  QInputDialog dialog = QInputDialog(this);
  dialog.setLabelText(message);
  QString longTitle = QString("Super long test title for making sure the widget will show all of the stupid long title.");
  dialog.setWindowTitle(longTitle);
  dialog.setInputMode(QInputDialog::TextInput);
  auto fontMetrics = dialog.fontMetrics();
  auto width = fontMetrics.boundingRect(longTitle).width();
  dialog.resize(width + 200, dialog.rect().height());
  const int ret = dialog.exec();
```